# Jenkins: How To Build multiple projects from a TFS repository?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, jenkins

I have set my workspace directory to `C:\jenkins_builds\workspace` and I want to build `ProjA` and `ProjB`, each having a local workfolder (same as project name).

When fetching the source code from my repository, the first two things the TFS plugin does are:

```
tf workspace -new %workspace-name-A%;%user-name% -server:%my-server%

tf workfold -map $%branch% ProjA -workspace:%workspace-name-A% -server:%my-server%
```

Which goes fine when building `ProjA`. The problem is, the first command maps the root directory from the repository directly to my `C:\jenkins_builds\workspace` directory. The second command does what I actually want, i.e. mapping `%branch%` to the `ProjA` subfolder. Later on, when building `ProjB`, the first command fails (and consequently the build) with the following error message:

```
The path C:\jenkins_builds\workspace is already mapped in workspace %workspace-name-A%;%user-name%.
```

OK, it seems like a bad idea to map the root directory to the work directory. But why does this automatically happen when the TFS plugin runs the `workspace new` line? Currently I have to clean things up between building `ProjA` and `ProjB` by running the -unmap command.

My team is using Team Foundation 3.0.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's not the `workspace -new` line that's causing this, it's the second line which creates a working folder mapping.  Working folder mappings must be unique for a server path inside a workspace.

Comment: Edward, thank you for your feedback. That's what I initially thought. The second line creates the mapping between the branch name and the project subfolder (as one might think). However, after running the commands from the command prompt, it turns out the first one actually maps the working folder "C:\jenkins_builds\workspace" with "$/" in the TFS repository. Quite counter-intuitive, right? This is what causes my head-ache.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same situation and there are 2 ways to solve this:

- **use different workspace-root-directories for the two builds**
  This results in the need for two checkouts => double the space and slower, but better isolation between the two builds
- **"hardcode" the workspace name to the same for both builds**
  By default jenkins creates a workspace containing the build name, which can be changed in the "advanced" section of the TFS config, and then you can use the same workspace-/workfolder-mapping for several builds - in our case we called them `ProjectName_${NODE_NAME}` so it even works on several nodes

Comment: Thank you for your advice! The second solution seems good enough for us, even though it may have some drawbacks. We have failed to use your first solution though. If I am not mistaken, the workspace root directory is global for Jenkins, right? Could you explain how to implement the first solution?

Comment: No, each job in Jenkins has its own workspace root - if your builds have the same, you must have changed them already; by default it is `${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/workspace` (found in the main jenkins settings at the top after hitting "advanced")...