# We are not able to retrieve data from multiple project paths in TFS to single workspace in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, tfs

We are trying to retrieve multiple project paths in TFS into the single folder for example PFB the list of project paths

`$/Integrations/Interfaces/GlobalComponents/Main/IIB_WorkSpace

$/Integrations/Interfaces/Items

$/Integrations/Interfaces/Commons`

i need to retrieve my project artifacts from above project paths  into a single folder where i can use that folder as jenkins workspace for build job in jenkins

I have used Multiple SCM plugin , I have added three TFS configurations with individual paths which mentioned above , when i am trying to run the build job, only first two paths ,i am able to retrieve the artifacts , third path when i checked the logs it says it retrieved 162 resources but i cannot see any file inside that folder related to that project path , I have used common TFS workspace for all three , Pls let me know if any one who has succeeded in retrieving project artifacts from multiple project paths, Pls do let me know

Comment: Did you check this option ?

Pull the code from all three TFS paths to separate folders and then copy them all to a single folder of interest.

Comment: Did your issue solved?

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT No Not yet

Comment: @BaskarLingamRamachandran How do i copy them all to a single folder of interest?

Answer (score 0):

The build project in Jenkins only support to set one path of TFS. Here are some workaround methods in these threads that you could have a try:

1.[How do you pull multiple TFS repos into a single Jenkins job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431142/how-do-you-pull-multiple-tfs-repos-into-a-single-jenkins-job)

2.[Jenkins: How To Build multiple projects from a TFS repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939661/jenkins-how-to-build-multiple-projects-from-a-tfs-repository)